# How can I listen to sort order change event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database Form that's configured to launch in datasheet view (`Default View = Datasheet`). I'd like to register an event handler in VBA so my code is notified whenever someone changes the sort order (order by) of the datasheet view.

I've tried building an event handler for the `Form_ApplyFilter` event, which appears to fire whenever the sort order is changed, but it appears that in the event handler, the `Form.OrderBy` isn't updated with the new value, which means I can't act on the sort order changes. Here's my actual method:

```
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)
    ' If this is an event that could cause the sort to change, make sure that the TransactionId is taken into consideration
    ' Interestingly, this event fires whenever someone filters OR SORTS the datasheet view.
    If ApplyType = acApplyFilter Or ApplyType = acFilterByForm Or ApplyType = acShowAllRecords Then
        Debug.Print "OrderBy: " & Me.OrderBy
        ' Argh! OrderBy is still the previous value, not the new one the user just set!
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I make my VBA code get notified whenever someone changes the sort order?

#### Some background

We've got a data set that includes a date, and we'd like to allow the user to order by that date (e.g. see the newest rows first). However, there is no unique constraint on this date field, and there are sometimes multiple rows with the same date. In these cases, Access breaks the tie by falling back on the natural order, which happens to be the primary key id in this case. But, this throws the users off, since they enter them in order of oldest to newest, and then go to view the data in order of newest to oldest, and see some rows "out of order", since they have the same date and are effectively sorted ascending by id within that group. I'm trying to programmatically add an `ORDER BY Id DESC` clause when they have sorted by date to show newest rows first so that they actually see the rows in order from newest to oldest.

I'm aware it's also a bit non-standard to be using a form for this, as you might think a query would do, but we needed the view to remain editable, and the view contains calculated fields, so our solution was to use a form so that we can configure different data sources for the editable and calculated fields so that the editable fields remain editable.

Comment: I tested code and the revised order criteria is printed. How does user apply sort or filter - with the ribbon tools? That is what I tested. Also, when closing form I see it has saved the revised order criteria in OrderBy property.

Comment: I also tested right click menu and same outcome. I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: @June7 Reproduction is hit-or-miss for me, too, so maybe I'm using the development tools wrong? At first, the event seems to give me the correct `OrderBy` value, but if I make a change to the method in the Access VBA editor (and save it), then re-launch the form, now the `OrderBy` value isn't reflected. Is that normal/expected?

Comment: Exactly what change? Seems not all details have been provided in question. What is the code to 'programmatically add an ORDER BY Id DESC clause'?

Comment: @June7 Literally adding a debug statement, e.g. `Debug.Print("OrderBy: " & Me.OrderBy)` as the first line of the method would cause the reported `OrderBy` value to be incorrect. Thanks to your comments, I'm pretty certain this is just a quirk with Access' VBA editor. If you write an answer that points out that my implementation was actually correct, I'll accept it.

Comment: You are talking about the Debug line in posted code? I copy/pasted your code and it works for me as already described. I have no idea why you experience different and therefore I don't have answer that resolves issue.